# How to update two models?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select option and a list and I want to update the list when the option is selected. I've tried something but without success. The request to update the notes doesn't fire. See the code below.

```
<select 
 ng-change="timeline.selectNote()" ng-model="timeline.selectedNote" ng-options="opt as opt.NoteContent for opt in timeline.noteOptions">
      <option value="">-- save note --</option>
    </select>
   <ul>
</select>

  <ul ng-change="timeline.selectNote()" ng-model="timeline.updateNotes"  
    ng-repeat="note in timeline.notes">
<table border=4 bordercolor=#778899">
<tr>
<td>
{{note.Date_id}}<br>
{{note.NoteContent}}
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br><br>
</url>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and JS

```
crmControllers.controller('TimelineCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
 function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $http.get('http://local.sx.com:8080/timeline/API?emailsId=' + $routeParams.emailsId, {withCredentials: true})
    .success(function(timelines) {
        $scope.timelines = timelines;
       angular.forEach(timelines, function(timeline) {

          $http.get('http://local.sx.com:8080/note/noteAPI?&email=' 
            +timeline.Email+ '&emailsId=' + $routeParams.emailsId, {withCredentials: true}).
            success(function(note) {
            timeline.noteOptions = note.NoteOptions;
            timeline.notes = note.Notes;

            timeline.selectNote = function() {
$http.get('http://local.sx.com:8080/note/addNoteAPI?&email=' 
            +timeline.Email+ '&noteContent=' + timeline.selectedNote.NoteContent+
            '&emailsId=' +$routeParams.emailsId, {withCredentials: true}).
            success(function(addNoteRsp) {
            timeline.updateNotes  = function(){
            $http.get('http://local.sx.com:8080/note/noteAPI?&email=' 
            +timeline.Email+ '&emailsId=' + $routeParams.emailsId, {withCredentials: true}).
            success(function(note) {
            timeline.noteOptions = note.NoteOptions;
            timeline.notes = note.Notes;
            });
        };

            console.log(addNoteRsp);
            });

            console.log(timeline.noteOptions);
      };

          });
       });
    });
```

Btw does my code looks quite ugly or this is just how all js looks like ?(i.e. never never ending brackets)

Comment: It looks like "timeline" is not defined in your controller scope.

Comment: it looks defined to me ``  timeline.noteOptions = note.NoteOptions;``

Answer (score 0):

there are few things which i am not able to understand...

```
<ul ng-change="timeline.selectNote()" ng-model="timeline.updateNotes"  
    ng-repeat="note in timeline.notes">
```

why ng-change and ng-model on the ul

```
ng-model="timeline.updateNotes"  

timeline.updateNotes  = function(){
```

updateNotes is a function, it can not be used as ng-model

given that you are you want notes for each timeline, you can just directly call the function, why wait for change??

**EDIT**

just to answer you comment...

if you have provided some way of saving the notes either button or form, you can do it as below

```
<button ng-click="updateNotes()" text="save"></button>
```

or

```
<form ng-submit="updateNotes()">
    <button type="submit" text="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: My whole is issue is that I want to make another http request  to the notes API  after a note is saved so that the client can see what exactly was saved. Currently after the note is saved the notes list ( note.notes is not updated. I was thinking that if I use ng-change="timeline.selectNote() on both the select option drop-down and the notes block it will trigger something to update the notes list

Comment: there must be some button which does the save.. so call the save on ng-click of that button or if you are using the form then call save on ng-submit of the form

Comment: actually there is no such button. The client has a drop-down list like "Mark read", "Mark unread" in webmail clients which updates the message read or unread just that in my case it posts a note from a preselected list.